# Getting UTC timezone in the format UTC +/-

Tags: javascript

I want to get the users timezone in relation to UTC and then display it UTC +/- . for example a California user should show UTC -8 (or -7 depending), while Bahrain would show UTC +3, etc.

The following code doesn't tell me if it's plus or minus tho, it just gives the answer 7 at the moment. How do I get it to give me a plus or minus sign?

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
document.write(offset / 60);
```

[Here's a fiddle of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/SquareGiraffe/p8zg9ozb/2/)

Comment: if you can use library you can checkout **Moment js**library, http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/

Comment: Not sure what you mean. When I run this, it logs "UTC -10".

Comment: hmmm.. where are you? Australia?

Comment: Ah, I get it, it displays a positive integer for when UTC is in front the current time, and a negative integer for when UTC is behind the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple.

```
var offset = - new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
document.write((offset > 0 ? '+' : '') + offset / 60);
```